# Catch note messages in AutoHotKeys

Tags: error-handling, autohotkey

I have this line

```
!ك:: send {Right}
```

It works well when my keyboard lang is Arabic, but when lang is English the keyboard does not have this char (ك) so AutoHotKeys gives me this message:

[image]

I am fine that AHK will not run this line, but I want to disable the note message.
I tried Try Catch, and OnError but both didn't work,
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another implementation using the `GetKeyVK()` function:

```
if GetKeyVK("ك") {
    Hotkey, !ك, NameYourHotkeyHere
    Hotkey, !+ك, AnotherNameHere
    Hotkey, ^ك, AndAnotherHere
    Hotkey, ^+ك, AlsoHere
}

return

NameYourHotkeyHere:
    Send {Right}
return

AnotherNameHere:
    Send +{Right}
return

AndAnotherHere:
    Send {End}
return

AlsoHere:
    Send {LShift down}{End down}{End up}{LShift up}
return
```

Comment: This one did the trick :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this. Since I don't have an Arabic keyboard, I can't test this particular example. Give it a shot.

```
#Persistent

; From https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/Languages.htm
arabicLangCodes := "0401,0801,0c01,1001,1401,1801,1c01,2001,2401,2801,2c01,3001,3401,3801,3c01,4001"

; Get the Language Identifier for the input language
; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout
langIdentifier := SubStr(Format("0x{:x}", DllCall("User32\GetKeyboardLayout", "Int", 0)), -3)

if InStr(arabicLangCodes, langIdentifier) {
    Hotkey, !ك, TestHotkey, On
}

return

TestHotkey:
    Msgbox % "Hotkey is active."
return
```

Comment: Hey @pizzashi, thanks for your answer, maybe I didn't explain well. You don't need to have the Arabic letters to test, because the problem happens when my keyboard lang is English, and it does not recognize the Arabic letter, then it gives me that warning message, all I need here is to suppress  that warning message, because I use Arabic letters many times, so AHK gives me many warning messages. I tried the code and it didn't make it.

Comment: I don't think there's a native way to suppress that warning. The code above dynamically adds the `!ك` hotkey when the detected input language is one of the Arabic regions, otherwise it won't be added. So when the detected input language is for example, English (US), the hotkey will not be added. Have you tried the above code while in Arabic keyboard and then pressing  `!ك`?

Comment: Apparently, there's a much more elegant solution in the [forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=40323) that uses the `GetKeyVK()` function. While it's still a workaround, it's much better and robust because it's shorter and it scans for the key (not the language) directly.

Comment: GetKeyVK() is very good, so I tried this code
```
If GetKeyVK("ك") 
  !ك:: send {Right}
  !+ك:: send +{Right}
  ^ك:: send {End}
  ^+ك:: Send {LShift down}{End down}{End up}{LShift up}
return
```
but still ahk gives those messages. I think these messages happens on the lexical parsing before actual execution.

Comment: Ah, that's not how you use it. Hotkeys need the `#If` directive (`if` doesn't work on them), and even then, the error still shows up. So you'll need to add the hotkey dynamically using the `Hotkey` command. I'll add another answer that does what you want to implement.